# Ember.js How to get controller in needs which is nested controllerName

Tags: controller, ember.js, nested-routes

I want to use `this.get('controllers.pack.query');` to get
`App.PackQueryController` in `App.PackController`, but failed.

I think the problem is Ember use `pack` not `pack.query` as `controllerName`
when it tries to get the controller.
Although I can get the controller by `this.controllerFor('pack.query')`,
but Ember says it is deprecated, please use `needs` instead

My router map likes below and I've defined `needs: ['pack.query']` in `App.PackController`

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('pack', function () {
        this.route('index', {path: '/:pack_id'})
        this.route('query');
    });
});

App.PackController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['pack.query'],
    queryPack: function () {
        var packQueryCtrller = this.get('controllers.pack.query');            

        Ember.debug('packQueryCtrller: ' + packQueryCtrller);
        //DEBUG: packQueryCtrller: undefined

        packQueryCtrller.queryPack(); //faild packQuery is undefined
    }
});

App.PackQueryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    queryPack: function (queryKey) {
        //...do query pack
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use camel case, not dot notation for this.

Your pack controller should be

```
 App.PackController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: ['packQuery'],
   queryPack: function () {
     var packQueryCtrller = this.get('controllers.packQuery');            

     Ember.debug('packQueryCtrller: ' + packQueryCtrller);
     //DEBUG: packQueryCtrller: undefined

     packQueryCtrller.queryPack(); //faild packQuery is undefined
   }
});
```

Comment: This does not work post ember-cli 0.2.3. See the answer by @rog for a working solution.

Answer (score 35):

[`Ember.inject.controller()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller) should be used to access a controller.  Use it like so:

**Setting**

```
...
myController: Ember.inject.controller('pack'),
nestedController: Ember.inject.controller('pack/query')
...
```

**Getting**

```
...
this.get('myController');
this.get('nestedController');
...
```

The answer above was updated to reflect the `needs` [deprecation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11767) in Ember 1.13.5 (released July 19, 2015).  I've left the old answers below, but shouldn't be used unless you're using an older version of Ember.

---

**[DEPRECATED] Accessing nested controllers from other controllers using [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_needs):**

Set `needs` on the controller:

```
...
needs: ['pack/query'],
...
```

Then access it using:

```
this.get('controllers.pack/query');
```

---

**[DEPRECATED] Accessing nested controllers from routes:**

Ideally, `actions` should be put on a Route.  If you're using the `needs` pattern outlined above in your `actions` on a controller, consider refactoring.

You can access nested controllers from a Route using [`controllerFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor) like so:

```
this.controllerFor('pack/query')
```

Comment: Updated again to reflect new versions (Ember 1.11.1 and ember-cli 0.2.3)

Comment: Thank you for this, there is surprisingly little information out there on this subject and getting to it seems to be a matter of stumbling blindly through the dark.

Comment: Updated again to reflect a newer version (Ember 1.13.5) that introduced a deprecation of the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer, inject, syntax for same use case

```
accountQueueController: Ember.inject.controller('account/queue'),
...
this.get('accountQueueController.model.myProperty')
```

source: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/needs-with-nested-controller/8083/6